# Using Meteor with Requirejs

Tags: javascript, requirejs, meteor, amd

How can I integrate requirejs in a meteor app and use AMD–modules, e.g for my Backbone modules?
Has anybody done that and can tell me what steps are needed to get this working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One simple answer (though maybe not the one you're looking for) is that you can simply use the two independently.  In other words, load all of your meteor scripts, then start your require-ified scripts loading.  Your require-ified scripts will be able to use the Meteor stuff just fine, without having to "import" any of it in via Require's loader.

If you *want* to have to import it, you should instead create a Require "shim" for it.

Comment: Last time I played with meteor (v0.4) it didn't have require/commonjs support. I think the only real option was/is to write your own wrapper plugin for meteor, or manually copy the required files into your meteor filesystem.

Comment: @machineghost: Thanks, that sounds like a reasonable approach

Comment: @crapthings: I think that is a commonjs import in node

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I loaded [Aloha Editor](http://www.aloha-editor.org/Content.Node/index.html) in Meteor and IronRouter. Aloha uses **requirejs** to load all its dependencies.

1. Unzip the Aloha distribution in **public/alohaeditor**.
2. Move all Aloha css files, except aloha-common-extra.css, to **client/lib/alohaeditor** (don't forget files from the plugins folder).
3. In all Aloha css files, turn relative paths into absolute paths (replace all '../' by '/alohaeditor/').
4. Install the [wait-on-lib](https://github.com/DerMambo/wait-on-lib) Meteor package.
5. Add the following hook to your route:

   ```
   onBeforeAction: function(pause)
       {           
       // Dynamically load require.js
       var one = IRLibLoader.load('/alohaeditor/lib/require.js', 
           {
           success: function(){ console.log('Successfully loaded require.js'); },
           error: function(){ console.log('Error loading require.js'); }
           });
       if(!one.ready())
           return pause();

       // Aloha settings
       Aloha = window.Aloha || {};
       Aloha.settings = Aloha.settings || {};
       Aloha.settings.baseUrl = '/alohaeditor/lib/';
       Aloha.settings.plugins = Aloha.settings.plugins || {};
       Aloha.settings.plugins.load = 'common/ui, common/format, common/link, common/table, common/list, common/block, common/undo, common/contenthandler, common/paste, common/commands, common/abbr';

       // Dynamically load aloha.js
       var two = IRLibLoader.load('/alohaeditor/lib/aloha.js',
           {
           success: function(){ console.log('Successfully loaded aloha.js'); },
           error: function(){ console.log('Error loading aloha.js'); }
           });
       if(!two.ready())
           return pause();
       },
   ```