# how to integrate TinyMCE and CKEditor in Meteor JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I am trying to use CKEditor or TinyMCE editor in my project.
So I put TinyMCE folder in meteor public folder, also put

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<your installation path>/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea"
    });
</script>
```

in template head tag. 
However receiving following error.
**Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: `"http://localhost:3000/%3Cyour%20installation%20path%3E/tinymce/tinymce.min.js". (index):97`
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < tinymce.min.js:1
Uncaught ReferenceError: tinymce is not defined**

How do I fix this problem? It is same to CKEditor.
Is there any other rich editor ,which I can use in Meteor JS?

Comment: Here is how to integrate Aloha Editor in Meteor, maybe it can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13961737/using-meteor-with-requirejs/26315457#26315457

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you need to put everything from the CKEDITOR build download in the public folder. CKEDITOR comes with all sorts of stuff and references everything based on relative directories.

Your public folder should have a directory named ckeditor it should contain contain the following files and folders:

```
 adapters
 lang
 plugins
 skins
 ckeditor.js
 config.js
 contents.css
 styles.js
```

In your primary layout file reference CKEDITOR like so:

```
 <head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js"></script>
 </head>
```

In your template:

```
 <template name="yourTemplate">
   <textarea id="content" name="content"></textarea>
 </template>
```

Finally, in the rendered function of your template:

```
 Template.yourTemplate.rendered = function() {
   $('#content').ckeditor();
 };
```

Normally, you would say `this.$('#content').ckeditor()` but that doesn't work because CKEDITOR is in your public folder. As a result, you need to the global reference to the `#content` element.

Comment: Brandon thank you so much!! It worked perfectly,thanks again for your gentle answer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `/public` folder, put your files in `/client/compatibility`. Then initialize it in the template you want to use it.

```
Template.editor.rendered = function() {
  tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea'
  });
};
```

Comment: I tried it. When I put client/compatibility folder it gives "client/compatibility/tinymce/js/tinymce/plugins/example/dialog.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets <!DOCTYPE html> for you)" error.

Comment: I put it in /public folder then initialized it in the template as you said. Result I tinymce is not defined error disappeared, now only got Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < localhost:3000/%3Cyour%20installation%20path%3E/tinymce/tinymce.min.js:1

Comment: The DOCTYPE error is caused by the example HTML files you placed in that folder as well. You should only put the distribution .js file.

Answer (score 0):

This was the only result searching for wysiwyg:

https://github.com/mcrider/meteor-bootstrap-wysiwyg

```
meteor add mcrider:bootstrap-wysiwyg
```

Looks a bit simpler than CKEditor or TinyMCE but maybe that's ok for your project.

Comment: its really simple but I need editor featured as tinyeditor. Anyway thanks for suggestion.