# how to integrating ck Editor with meteor

Tags: javascript, css, html, meteor

i followed some tutorial to add ck editor with the meteor but it not working me can anybody have a idea how to keep the ck editor files sources with  meteor
following is my html file

```js
 Template.hello.rendered = function() { 
    $('#content').ckeditor(); 
     };
```

```html
<template name="hello">
   <textarea id="content" name="content"></textarea>
 </template>
```

can anybody solve this problem i am getting plain textbox while run the code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to integrate TinyMCE and CKEditor in Meteor JS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26010749/how-to-integrate-tinymce-and-ckeditor-in-meteor-js)

Comment: thanks i done it .Standard package  but i am not getting the option in the image and attach file  upload option can anybody know if yes please share me an idea.

Comment: full features package is not working it showing an error  not loading the icons only displaying textarea